# firebase cloud messaging doesn't get me token without filter breaker

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm new to swift programming and I need to use firebase.
But when I try to get token, it doesn't get me a token.
And when I connect to a filter breaker it works fine.
I checked my certificates and I am using firebase cloud messaging sample.

Comment: Did you add both your development and distribution certificate in firebase?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a minute to read these awesome two guides about asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). While some contributors appear to have psychic like abilities - we really aren't. So please include code snippets in your questions so we understand what you are trying to do and may be able to spot the error.

Comment: @DarshanKarekar yes.I added both of them,I can get token with filter breaker but in normal way I can't.